# How to use scriptella to read files from amazon S3 and load into a database say postgres. Any pointers on how to build a new connector for aws S3 ?

Tags: etl, scriptella

How do I use scriptella to read files from amazon S3. I do not see any S3 connector. In general how a remote set of files can be accessed using http/https. How easy it is to enhance the AbstractConnection to achieve this. Any pointers welcome.

Comment: Which filetypes are you are trying to access (CSV/XML/...)?

Comment: Are those files publicly available (ie: you can access them from their url with no need to authenticate)?

Comment: Yes - those files are available . no need to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

As you can access those files without authentication, you can use the same connectors you would use if the files where local: they should support http urls (I have tried only with csv driver and a csv file in dropbox and it worked):

```
<connection id="in" driver="csv" url="http://hostname.s3.amazonaws.com/csv_files/file1.csv"/>
```